# generate log .txt file on PC for arduino serial terminal log (send and receive commands)

Tags: arduino, serial, c++

I am trying to generate a .txt file on my Windows 10 PC of Arduino serial terminal data. I am not using SD card on Arduino Mega board just need to send commands to Arduino baord from serial terminal and save the generated results in .txt file on PC.

Please guide for best possible solutions.

Thank you....

Comment: Capturing a log file is a feature offered by many serial terminal programs, it's also easy to do yourself in something like python with pyserial, especially if you want to automate sending the commands and creating the log files or name them in a pattern, or to filter some of what you save, or really any custom behavior...

Comment: Existing question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/54/saving-arduino-sensor-data-to-a-text-file is less specific to saving a text file than yours but includes a number of solutions for doing so among its answers

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you for reply, Can I send the commands one by one using pyserial? Actually in my task, I need to send commands one after another and need to log the data in .txt file. I ma new to python Can you share some key inputs or any reference...... It would be great help.